# custom api-gateway id - Amazonaws

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, bucket

When I create an API on amazonaws it gives me a random ID like this:

`randomID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Is it possible to change the ID to a preferred one like the company name? if yes, how can I do it?

`preferredID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

**Another question**

Can another person create an S3 bucket with the same address? as both api and S3 buckets use the same AWS regional and domain `us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Setting up custom domain names for REST APIs - Amazon API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html):

Custom domain names are simpler and more intuitive URLs that you can provide to your API users.

After deploying your API, you (and your customers) can invoke the API using the default base URL of the following format:

```
https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage
```

where `api-id` is generated by API Gateway, `region` (AWS Region) is specified by you when creating the API, and `stage` is specified by you when deploying the API.

The hostname portion of the URL (that is, api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com) refers to an API endpoint. The default API endpoint can be difficult to recall and not user-friendly.

**With custom domain names**, you can set up your API's hostname, and choose a base path (for example, `myservice`) to map the alternative URL to your API. For example, a more user-friendly API base URL can become:

```
https://api.example.com/myservice
```